# How to run my for loop with same i if i want?

Tags: python, for-loop, if-statement

```
def MH(x,y,sigma=0.1,iterasyon=100):
     import random
     import numpy as np
     a=np.array([1])
     b=np.array([1])

     for i in range(5):


         ayap=float(random.gauss(a[i],sigma))
         byap=float(random.gauss(b[i],sigma))

         rss0 = np.sum((a[i]+b[i]*x-y)**2)
         rss1=np.sum((ayap+byap*x-y)**2)
         if random.random() <= min(1,rss1/rss0):

             a=np.append(a,ayap)
             b=np.append(b,byap)

     return a
```

So if my if condition wont work, i want to start again with same i. How can i do that? I tried to put a else: i=i-1 but didnt work

Answer (score 1):

You can't really do that with a for loop (at least not without a lot of weird gymnastics revolving around generators).  You *can* use a `while` loop:

```
i = 0
while i < 5:
   # Do stuff

   if condition:
       # Increment ...
       i += 1
```

Comment: Thanks man. Very useful but sadly i cant upvote your answer yet because i just created my account.

Answer (score 0):

```
def MH(x,y,sigma=0.1,iterasyon=100):
     import random
     import numpy as np
     a=np.array([1])
     b=np.array([1])
     i, c = 0, 0

     while i < 5:
         try:   
             ayap=float(random.gauss(a[i],sigma))
             byap=float(random.gauss(b[i],sigma))

             rss0 = np.sum((a[i]+b[i]*x-y)**2)
             rss1=np.sum((ayap+byap*x-y)**2)
             if random.random() <= min(1,rss1/rss0):

                 a=np.append(a,ayap)
                 b=np.append(b,byap)
         except: 
             # handle some error here, maybe
             c = c + 1
             # if code fails 3 times, break
             if c == 3:
                 break

         else:
             # only increment when there was no exception
             i = i + 1
     return a
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use an extra while loop:

```
def MH(x,y,sigma=0.1,iterasyon=100):
     import random
     import numpy as np
     a=np.array([1])
     b=np.array([1])

     for i in range(5):

         while True:
             ayap=float(random.gauss(a[i],sigma))
             byap=float(random.gauss(b[i],sigma))

             rss0 = np.sum((a[i]+b[i]*x-y)**2)
             rss1=np.sum((ayap+byap*x-y)**2)
             if random.random() <= min(1,rss1/rss0):

                 a=np.append(a,ayap)
                 b=np.append(b,byap)
             else:
                 break

     return a
```

As soon as your if-condition is not met, the interpreter breaks out of the loop.

The kind of logic you want is very prone to run into an infinite loop. Watch out for that! That concern is equally valid for mgilson's answer.